# simple sql counting and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

im currently doing a sql problem.

Q: Using Product table, find out the number of makers who produce only one model.

The database scheme consists of four tables:
Product(maker, model, type)

The table "Product" includes information about the maker, model number, and type ('PC', 'Laptop', or 'Printer'). It is assumed that model numbers in the Product table are unique for all the makers and product types.

The queries:

```
select count(maker) from product group by maker having count(model)=1

Select count(*) from (select maker from product group by maker having count(model)=1)as A
```

I was wondering what is the difference between these two queries they look the same to me, but apprently the second one is the correct ans.

Comment: No both are different first will give count per maker and will give rows deoends on how many makers u have second will give for all maker that one mode and will result in a single row

Comment: Do you have any NULLs in maker?  COUNT(column_name) ignores nulls in column_name, COUNT(asterisk) give you a straight row count.  If you change the top query to COUNT(asterisk) and get the same results, I'd bet that's the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at the first query.

```
create table product ( maker int not null, model int not null );
insert into product (maker, model) values (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1);

select maker from product group by maker having count(model)=1
MAKER      
-------
      2
      3
      4
      5
```

i.e. maker 2,3,4,5 have exactly one product.

```
select count(maker) from product group by maker having count(model)=1
```

each maker occurs ones, i.e.

```
-------
      1
      1
      1
      1
```

The other query on the other hand, will count how many makers there are:

```
select count(*) from (select maker from product group by maker having count(model)=1)

--------
      4
```